# Is that possible to organize nightly builds at Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

Is that possible to organize nightly builds at Ubuntu Server using MSVC++ compiler?
I mean is it possible to install Visual Studio 2008 and run msbuild.exe in Wine by scheduler to compile C++ solutions?

**EDIT:** I have used VirtualBox with Win7 in in. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen anyone successfully building projects with MSVC++ under Wine. However, the only thing I can find is a bug concerning building .NET projects using msbuild.exe under Wine (bug is [here](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10467))

How about running a VirtualBox with e.g. Windows XP, and using shared folders and some clever hacks (to start the compilation)?

Comment: VirtualBox requires additional resources (e.g. memory or processor). So Wine more preferred while it used for other purposes also.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I don't think you will be lucky on this one, but it would be neat!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should be possible. However, the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) suggests that your luck may not be good. The best thing to do is to install it and try.

Comment: I have tried it already. MSVC installer failed to work under Wine. May be there are some silent install mode switches needed. Or some /WINECOMPATMODE switch.

Comment: If you haven't had much luck, and the appdb doesn't look good, then I think it's safe to say it can't be done on the current version of wine. Maybe Codeweaver's version of Wine will work, but that's not free.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Maybe someone has experience of such installation. I'll wait for that mega-admin :)